# Want to know how to reveal a WordPress theme, considering the theme name is hidden?

Tags: plugin-development, customization, theme-development, child-theme, theme-options

Please can anyone advise, I want to know what If a WordPress theme is hidden from the directory folder? And a result no online extension will able to track the original theme name used to create the website.

Is there any other alternate way to find out the theme name?
Looking for an answer.

Thanks for bringing your attention.
Jamil

Comment: Just look into the path of some css files, there must be a folder after wp-content/themes/something/style.css for example.

Comment: If it is "hidden from the directory folder", how should WordPress be able to load it? Do you have access via FTP? Then check wp-content/themes first. If it is not there, WP might be configured to load the themes via another folder instead.

Comment: There's also no guarantee that a WordPress-built website is using a publicly available theme anyway, so finding out the name won't necessarily tell you anything. There is also [the REST API themes endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/themes/), but I don't know if it's possible to just query that for the current theme - it doesn't work for me at first glance.

Comment: Or you could always just email the site admin and ask them?